# Merge array into object properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a trivial issue where I have two simple objects like this

```
var state = {
    Value1: "Something",
    Value2: "Else"
};


var claims = [
    "Viewing",
    "Editing",
    "Delete"
];
```

and I would like to create an object that looks like this.

```
var newState = {
    Value1: "Something",
    Value2: "Else",

    /* Array merged into properties with defaults. */
    Viewing: true,
    Editing: true,
    Delete: true
};
```

I considered using jQuery `$.map()` and alternatively `Object.assign()` (which seems to be closer to what I want) but I cant seem to work out exactly how to achieve the result I need.

So as the heading states, how do I merge an array into an existing object as properties while also setting default values?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have explicitly described two approaches that I have considered but nether of them achieve what I want. Further, clearly given by the responses below it isn't that simple a problem to achieve the above without conviluted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simple given example try the following:

```js
var state  = {Value1:"Something",Value2:"Else"}; 
    claims = ["Viewing","Editing","Delete"];

let res = Object.assign(state, claims.reduce((a,c) => {a[c] = true; return a},{}))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property using variable name with `obj[myStringAsName] = value`

```js
var state = {
    Value1: "Something",
    Value2: "Else"
};


var claims = [
    "Viewing",
    "Editing",
    "Delete"
];

var newState = state;
claims.forEach(function(item){
 newState[item] = true;
})

console.log(newState)
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted the array to object using `reduce` and merged both objects

```js
var state = {
    Value1: "Something",
    Value2: "Else"
};


var claims = [
    "Viewing",
    "Editing",
    "Delete"
];
var obj = claims.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
            acc[cur] = true;
            return acc;
          }, {});

var returnedData = Object.assign(state, obj);

console.log(returnedData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use destructuring and a simple [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const state = {
    Value1: "Something",
    Value2: "Else"
};


const claims = [
    "Viewing",
    "Editing",
    "Delete"
];

const newState = {
  ...state
}

claims.forEach(prop => newState[prop] = true);

console.log(newState)
```